# Unable to log in on onepage checkout page

Tags: onepage-checkout, login

I am unable to log in as a customer. I have changed the password and email for this customer to my own that I want to test with, and still I can't log in. I am getting message that email or password are incorrect. I know for a fact they are correct. Where is the problem happening that is stopping me from logging in?

Comment: can you log in using the same credentials in the normal login page? And what is your magento version 1 or 2?

Comment: Magento v.1.9.2.4. And no, I can't log in.

Comment: then most probably the credentials are wrong. If that's not it, maybe you have a module preventing this from happening. Does it happen for one specific customer or all of them?

Comment: For all of them. YOu are correct. I have found out that there is a module that extends Mage_Customer_AccountController and reimplements some login methods. It is preventing me from login, for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments...
If you cannot login for a specific user then most probably the credentials are wrong.
If this happens for all the customers then most probably there is an extension that affects the login process preventing a proper login.

Comment: Credentials are correct. There is a module interfering with login and checking out functionalities. After I disabled it, I can now log in and check out.